# how to activate particular tab on the basis of previous page in second html page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pie chart. Functionality is that when I select a particular section of pie chart, then it redirects to the next page with selected tab. I am able to get value of that pie chart section by using this code:

```
 var search = document.URL.split('?')[1];
```

Now my fight is how to enable particular tab on the next page on the basis of value of "search" variable.
Next when user comes direct to this page then 1st tab is enable by default. for this I used the code:

```
<div class="tab-pane in active" id="tab1">
```

I have tried in many ways(like `$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show()` or `using eq()`) but have no success. Please let me know if anyone can help me out.

Comment: Could you post an HTML/JS example of how your tabs are defined?

Comment: I meant in the original post :) Also a proper http://jsfiddle.net/ could be useful.

Comment: @ Thierry J. : Here I have defined tabs:                                                              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
<li id="tab1" class="active"><a href="#error"data-toggle="tab"> Error</a></li>                                                      <li id="tab2"><a href="#suspect" data-toggle="tab" >Suspect </a></li> </ul>                                                                 ...                                                                 <div class="tab-pane in active" id="error">                         <div class="tab-pane" id="suspect">

Comment: Are you using jquery-ui tabs widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();

        var search = document.URL.split('?')[1];
        switch (search) {
            case "error":
                $("#tab1 > a").click();
                break;
            case "suspect":
                $("#tab2 > a").click();
                break;
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li id="tab1" class="active"><a href="#error"data-toggle="tab"> Error</a></li>
        <li id="tab2"><a href="#suspect" data-toggle="tab" >Suspect </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-pane in active" id="error">
        Error
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="suspect">
        Suspect
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I replaced click() by show() as I want to enabled that selected tab on page load. Also I am calling this JS on page load (ex. <body onload="getTabEnable()">). But it not working. May be I am missing something.

Comment: The reason why I used `click` is because the tabs widget adds a event handler on the `click` event, that does many other things than just a `.show()`. Try with click, and see how it goes. Also calling this in `$(function() {...});` runs the code just after the page has been loaded, it sets the function as a handler of the event `ready` on the document.

Comment: Thank you Thierry. Now it is working good but i had to remove this line code $("#tabs").tabs(); . Thank you so much.